# Trouble with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have such string in PHP:

```
$data = '1;3;5;7;9';
```

And cycle:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($someArray); $i++)
{
   // If $i == any number in $data
}
```

What is the faster way to compare $i from cycle with numbers in string. I have to check that cycle-counter is in string.

Comment: COuld you elaborate a bit more on your question please :-) I don't exactly know what you're asking.

Comment: @Jamie, yeah, sorry, forgot about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just explode the `$data` into it's own array

```
$data = '1;3;5;7;9';

$numbers = explode(";", $data);

for($i=0; $i < count($someArray); $i++)
{
    if(in_array($i, $numbers))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the numbers as keys for an index:

```
$data = '1;3;5;7;9';
$index = array_flip(explode(';', $data));
```

Now you can simply use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) or [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) to check if that number is in `$data`:

```
for ($i=0, $n=count($someArray); $i<$n; ++$i) {
   if (array_key_exists($index, $i)) {
       // $i is in $data
   }
}
```

You can even do the reverse, iterate the numbers in `$data` and see if they are in the range from 0 to `count($someArray)`-1:

```
$data = '1;3;5;7;9';
$n = count($someArray);
foreach (explode(';', $data) as $number) {
    if (0 <= $number && $number < $n) {
        // $number is in range from 0 to $n-1
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `array_key_exists` more reliable than `in_array`?

Comment: @bschaeffer: It’s more efficient: `isset` and `array_key_exists` should be O(1) while `in_array` is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You could take this a step further if you are just looking for the values (no further logic within the loop).

```
$data = '1;3;5;7;9';
$numbers = explode(";", $data);

$result = array_intersect($numbers, range(0, count($someArray)));

print_r($result);
```